# Angular Nested, Arbitrary Content Projection

Tags: angular, ng-content

In Angular, is it possible to do something like

```
<my-component>
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <p>Some text</p>
  ...
</my-component
```

and then in `my-component` have it turn into

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Some text</h1>
</div>
<div class="container>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
...
```

where the number and types of elements to project is *arbitrary*? Each child element needs to be placed within a new `<div class="container">`, but the child elements could be any type and there is no set number of them.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the ng-content directive in the host component.
So in your example the my-component markup should look like this
`<ng-content><ng-content>`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily using `ng-content` with Multi-slot content projection ([Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection)):

```
<div class="container">
  <ng-content select="h1"></ng-content>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <ng-content select="p"></ng-content>
</div>
```